# Почему изменяется дочерний объект оригинала при попытке изменить дочерний объект копии оригинала?

Tags: javascript

Допустим, есть объект `user`:

```
const user = {
    id: 1,
    data: {
        age: 60
    }
};
```

Если я скопирую объект `user` в переменную `copy` одним из двух вариантов:

```
const copy = Object.assign({}, user);
```

или

```
 const copy = { ...user };
```

а затем изменю возраст скопированного пользователя:

```
copy.data.age = 20;
```

То почему `user.data.age` тоже изменится и как это предотвратить?

Comment: Насколько я понимаю работу `Object.assign` - он не делает глубокого копирования. `data` - это уже другой объект, с другой ссылкой

Comment: @Дмытрык Похоже на то. Какие тогда есть варианты?

Comment: Создайте свой метод, который будет делать глубокое копирование используя `Object.assign`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Объекты в javascript копируются по ссылке, а не по значению. Я так понимаю, Вы это знаете, раз пытаетесь копировать объекты данными способами. Но в этих случаях не создается "глубокая" копия объекта.

что происходит при `const obj2 = obj1;`

выполняется команда `создай новый якорь obj2 и соотноси его с такой же областью памяти, с которой соотносится obj1`.

что происходит при `const obj2 = { ...obj1 };`

выполняется команда `создай новый якорь obj2, соотнеси его с новой ячейкой памяти, и положи в нее следующие поля: поле А и положи туда значение поля А у obj1, поле В и положи туда значение поля В у obj1....`.

В данном случае выполняется команда `создай новый якорь copy, соотнеси его с новой ячейкой памяти, и положи в нее следующие поля: поле data и положи туда значение поля data у user`. Но в поле data у объекта user ссылка на область памяти, а не примитивное значение! И в поле data объекта copy передается та же ссылка!

Надеюсь не слишком путано объяснил.

P.S. Если Вам нужно действительно глубокое клонирование, то самый бронебойный способ для любого уровня вложенности это:

```
const obj2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj1));
```

Answer (score 2):

Если у вас в объектах только данные, которые совместимы с JSON, можно так:

```js
'use strict';

const user = {
    id: 1,
    data: {
        age: 60
    }
};

const userCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(user));

userCopy.data.age = 20;

console.log(userCopy);
console.log(user);
```

Если есть что-то несовместимое с JSON, тогда нужно писать рекурсивный обход дерева с глубоким копированием.

Comment: а можно пример данных, несовместимых с json?

Comment: Можно почитать здесь: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#Description

Comment: весьма любопытно, спасибо!