# Изменение массива в React

Tags: массивы, reactjs, native

Такой вопрос.

```
board =  [
        [1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1],
        [1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1],
        [1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1],
        [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
        [2,2,2,2,3,2,2,2,2],
        [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
        [1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1],
        [1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1],
        [1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1],
      ]
```

Это массив - шаблон.
Делаю копию
`const [arr, SetArr] = useState(board)`
Далее работаю с `arr`.

```
let arr2 = [...arr]
arr2[0][0] = 3
arr2[1][1] = 3
SetArr(arr2)
```

Изменения сохраняются и отображаются. НО. Если я хочу обновить массив arr и вернуть его к начальной точке, а именно: `SetArr(board)` получается ерунда какая-то. Архив не возвращается к начальной точке. Получается , что в board храниться изменённый массив равный `arr`. При этом, если сделать рестарт проекта то всё начинается с нуля и работает. Я не могу понять почему меняется board

Comment: Делайте новую строку перед и в конце кода, тогда правильно будет выглядеть код в вопросе.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему изменяется дочерний объект оригинала при попытке изменить дочерний объект копии оригинала?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/947771/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0

Answer (score 0):

Если объект содержит методы или массив содержит функции, то копирование с помощью JSON-преобразования не сработает. Тогда нужно смотреть в сторону библиотеке lodash

```
let arr2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(board))
```